# How to deploy already prepared jars with maven (continue the release)?

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I did `mvn release:perform` and it prepared all required jars and started to sign them with `maven-gpg-plugin`, when stuck, so I interrupted this process. I want to continue the release, without rolling back Git version bump commits, re-running tests etc.

I try something like `mvn deploy "-Dversion=1.0"` (where say 1.0 is the version for which jars are prepared; the current repo version is `1.1-SNAPSHOT`), but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you did not delete the release.properties and backup files, you can just rerun the command and it will pick up where it left off

Comment: @Tunaki the actual command was `mvn clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform`. When I try to re-run `mvn release:prepare release:perform` or just `mvn release:perform`, it assumes I want to release `1.1` and complains `target\checkout` directory is not empty.

Comment: Did it fail on prepare or perform? If it failed on prepare, you can run `release:prepare` again (provided the temp files were not deleted)

Comment: @Tunaki seems perform: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:perform (default-cli) on project foo: Unable to remove old checkout directory: Directory C:\path\to\foo\target\checkout unable to be deleted. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: "unable to be deleted" seems to imply the directory is currently in use. Is it? Maybe you have a window open in it?

Comment: @Tunaki yes, seems something was locking that directory. and actually `mvn release:prepare release:perfrom` tries to release `1.0` but it stuck on gpg signing again...

Comment: The locking process was `gpg.exe`